# How many different ways can you create an "alias" in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I only know of two ways: `alias foo=bar` and `function foo() { bar }`.

The reason I'm asking is that - all of a sudden in one of my bash sessions - I cannot run the `ln` command because `bash` is erroring out with `-bash: /usr/local/.../ln: No such file or directory` (where the `/usr/local/.../` is one of the entries in my `PATH` environment variable).

It's not a `PATH` issue though, because If I run `which ln` it outputs the expected binary of `/usr/bin/ln` (which I can run fine if I specify the absolute path).

I also checked for `ln` in my `alias` and `function` declarations, and there is nothing:

```
$ declare -f | grep ln
$ alias | grep ln
```

The problem is just occurring in one bash session. If I start a new shell, it works fine again, but I want to know what caused this problem all of a sudden in this one particular session of bash.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Be careful when using the `which` command. Better to use the `type ...` command.

```
$ type ln
ln is /bin/ln
```

You can also use the `whereis` command:

```
$ whereis ln
ln: /bin/ln /usr/share/man/man1p/ln.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ln.1.gz
```

Comment: You're right! When I run `type ln` I get `ln is hashed (/usr/local/.../ln)` which appears to be the problem, but what does it mean exactly that it's "hashed"? I've never heard of that feature in bash.

Comment: @etherice - Bash maintains a hash (a key=value list) of a command's name and where it's located. You can see the list with the `hash -l` command. It's dynamically built as you use commands.

Comment: @etherice - I just upvoted your question so you're only 4 pts away 8-). You can accept the answer when your issue's resolved and you feel it's the best answer.

Comment: @etherice - there someone else just upvoted you so now you have 16 pts.

Comment: @etherice to accept answers you don't need more than being the one that make the question ;)

Comment: Thanks! I ran `hash -r` to reset the command-to-path hashtable, and `ln` is back to working order now.